# C# Code Contracts: Are postconditions on members accessible from other threads useless?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, code-contracts

after some thinking I have concluded that postconditions in methods are useful only when imposed on the return value, *ref* and *out* parameters, but not on fields, neither static nor on any instance. The reason is that when that method is called, static analysis of that call can't do anything with postconditions on a field, because other threads might have already alter that field to any state, and therefore not necessarily meeting the postcondition. I conclude that postconditions imposed on anything accessible by more than one thread, which are basically only fields, are useless, and that leaves only the usefulness of postconditions on the return values and *out* and *ref* parameters. The invariant is the only form of postconditions on fields not negated by threading.

I'm asking whether this reasoning is faulty and whether I'm missing arguments for any non-meta purpose of postconditions on fields. With 'meta' I mean anything which could also be accomplished by other means, in particular by commenting.

Comment: If your code isn't threadsafe then post conditions are not the only thing that breaks. In that case your whole code is broken.

Comment: Why would a ref or out parameter be any different than a field?  **The out or ref parameter could be an alias to a field**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> static analysis of that call can't do
>   anything with postconditions on a
>   field

It can make sure that *you* have satisfied them. If another thread changes the value of a field such that when you return the postcondition does not hold, then your class is being used in a thread-unsafe manner as per its thread safety specification (otherwise the sync facilities it would implement to provide thread safety would have prevented this from happening in the first place). What you 're saying here is "if you use the class in a manner it does not support being used in, then postconditions don't help". But that's the least of your worries in this case.

> The invariant is the only form of
>   postconditions on fields not negated
>   by threading.

The same argument you used for postconditions can be used for class invariants: other threads may have started modifying the object and left it in an inconsistent state (they can do so as long as the public method that does it has not returned), so that when *you* return the invariant does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your response. And I agree, the postconditions are there to ensure the developer hasn't made any errors. The underlying problem of my question though, is the large amount of warnings I get. To get rid of those unresolved by the static checker because of threading, I don't need to know whether they are satisfied, but I need the static checker to know. Any suggestion on that besides spraying Code.Assume all over the place?

Comment: @JBSnorro: Unresolved because of threading? Are you sure about that? The static checker is surprisingly good, but there's a lot that it cannot do at this time. Are you sure it's the threading that prevents it from proving postconditions?

Comment: yes I'm sure. But in the situations I'm talking of, the static checker correctly issues the warning, as in, I would deduce the same conclusion. For instance when I have a method which ensures something trivial of a field(i.e. for a collection Capacity >= Count), then after a call to that method this condition isn't necessarily met(because of threading), and so in a statement a warning is issued that it couldn't prove capacity >= count. This simple condition should of course be an invariant, but consider a condition which is not always true, but is ensured by the first method.